# Reference request on the Schwartz class on integers

Tags: functional-analysis, reference-request, schwartz-space, reference-works

It's a well known fact that the Schwartz class over integers defined by
$$S(\mathbb{Z}^n)=\{\{a_m\}_{m\in\mathbb{Z^n}}\mid \sup_{m\in\mathbb{Z}^n}|m^\alpha a_m|<\infty, \forall \alpha\in\mathbb{N}^n\},$$
is a Frechet algebra. I've studied this in a Functional Analysis course in the past, now I'm just looking for a reference of this fact because I'd like to quote it on my master's thesis.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: "Schwartz" with a "t". :)

Comment: Haha thanks, I've just edited it.

Comment: It is the topological intersection ($U$ open in $H_\alpha$ implies $U\cap S$ open in $S(\Bbb{Z}^n)$) of the Hilbert spaces with norms $\sum |a_m|^2 (1+|m|^\alpha)$ it implies quite every property you need. The complex exponentials are an iromosphism to $C^\infty(\Bbb{R^n/Z^n})$ and the (product of) Hermite functions are an isomorphism to $S(\Bbb{R}^n)$

Comment: In case I don't find any reference to quote I'll have to prove some facts myself, and in that case your approach seems to solve it very quicly, so I'll consider it, Thanks!